# How to set the value of annotation-config to false?

Tags: java, spring

[Documentation is here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/classpath-scanning.html#beans-scanning-autodetection)

> You can disable the registration of AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor and CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor by including the annotation-config attribute with a value of false.

To my knowledge(I must have missed something.), the value of annotation-config cannot be set to false.

```xml
    <context:annotation-config value="false" /> <!-- error -->
    <context:annotation-config>
        <value>false</value>    <!-- error -->
        <!-- No Any Completion -->
    </context:annotation-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means setting `annotation-config` in `<context:component-scan>` , but not `value` in  `<context:annotation-config>`.

Codewise , it means the followings to disable them :

```xml
<context:component-scan annotation-config="false"/>
```